# RTC DS3231 Not resetting time on power loss

Tags: rtc

I'm completely removing power from a DS3231 RTC module and my call to `rtc.lostPower()` is never hit when I reconnect everything. I'm also removing the battery, I left it overnight and it remembers the time just before I disconnected everything, but doesn't register a power loss. I'm using this with a D1 mini.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(baud);

  if (!rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC.");
    while (1); // while true
  }

  if (rtc.lostPower()) {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, resetting time.");
    ConnectWiFi();
    GetNtpTime();
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    Serial.println("Time set after power loss");
  }
}
```

Comment: please add a link to the module datasheet and to the DS3231 datasheet

Comment: @jsotola: Here is the [datasheet of the DS3231](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf). The [`lostPower()` method](https://adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_r_t_c___d_s3231.html#a097dc15a79ec077073969432b1abcb88) returns the “Oscillator Stop Flag” from the status register (c.f. datasheet, p. 14).